# jquery saber se campo foi validade com padrão correto

Tags: jquery

Bom, tenho um campo de texto:

```
<input pattern="[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}" type="text" id="campo" required />
```

Como faço em `JQuery` para saber se o preenchimento está de acordo com o `padrão`?

Sim, eu sei que o `html5` já faz isso para mim.

Mas a validação vai ser feita por um `botão` de `fora` do `form`.

coia de maluco. Mas é assim que precisará ser feita.

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa de jQuery, a propria API de validação lhe permite isto.

Você pode usar o método `checkValidity` para verificar se o input é valido, então pode acessar as propriedades da propriedade `validity` para saber em que validações o `input` não passou.

```js
var campo = document.getElementById("campo");
var verifica = document.getElementById("verifica");
verifica.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (!campo.checkValidity()) {
    if (!campo.validity.valueMissing) {
      console.log("Campo Obrigatorio");
    } 
    if (!campo.validity.patternMismatch) {
      console.log("Campo com valor invalido.");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}" type="text" id="campo" required />
</form>
<input id="verifica" type="button" value="Verificar" />
```

a propriedade `validity` possui outros campos uteis.:

```
customError
patternMismatch
rangeOverflow
rangeUnderflow
stepMismatch
tooLong
typeMismatch
valueMissing
valid
```

**EDIT - Em resposta ao comentatio**

O objeto jQuery nada mais é que uma abstração para os seus objetos DOM, então ele acaba por funcioanar como um container para o mesmo, desta forma você irá conseguir ter acesso estes objetos pelo indice, de forma similar à como você acessar objetos em um Array.

`$("#campo")[0]` será semelhante a `document.getElementById("campo");`, porém com um overhead enorme.

```js
var campo = $("#campo");
var verifica = $("#verifica");
verifica.on("click", function (event) {
  if (!campo[0].checkValidity()) {
    if (!campo[0].validity.valueMissing) {
      console.log("Campo Obrigatorio");
    } 
    if (!campo[0].validity.patternMismatch) {
      console.log("Campo com valor invalido.");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input pattern="[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}" type="text" id="campo" required />
</form>
<input id="verifica" type="button" value="Verificar" />
```

Comment: Sim. Mas já uso JQuery. No caso ficaria assim? 
if (!$("#campo").checkValidity()

Comment: Consegui:if (!$("#cep")[0].checkValidity(). Obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosRocha, fiz uma edição na resposta.